# How to set vue-data after new vue and work for data-binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

e.g:
I need to add data-value after new vue and work for data-binding.

#### why i need to do that :

I know `it's work if i declare first on new Vue object`.
But there's a old project with a lot of layout-subject-page,if i need to add a vue global varible then i need to edit every page's vue data-value.

#### what i expected :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {}
})
app.$data.message = "test"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to dynamically add a new data prop *and* update the template to use that prop. While the former is possible, I don't believe the latter is.

Comment: @tony19 yes,i want it. `dynamically add a new data prop and update the template to use that prop` and work for adding after new  Vue object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done.

Vue runs internal setup on the initially declared data properties which won't happen if you try to declare them later.

From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html):

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance.

You can add new object/array items using `Vue.set` if that helps you.